# How do I get python code to loop every x mins between the times y and z?

Tags: python, loops, time, delay

This might be incredibly easy but how do I get python code to loop every x mins between the times y and z?

For example if I wanted my script to run between midnight (00:00) through to 10 pm (22:00) looping every 5 minutes.

Comment: This looks like a job for the operating system's scheduler, not for the script itself.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, the script in question will be distributed and ran at different locations, this is why I specifically wanted to run it loop it in the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the *[sched](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sched.html#module-sched)* module in the standard library.  Here's an example of calling a function once per second, starting five seconds in the future, and ending ten seconds in the future:

```
from sched import scheduler
from time import time, sleep

s = scheduler(time, sleep)

def run_periodically(start, end, interval, func):
    event_time = start
    while event_time < end:
        s.enterabs(event_time, 0, func, ())
        event_time += interval
    s.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    def say_hello():
        print 'hello'    

    run_periodically(time()+5, time()+10, 1, say_hello)
```

Alternatively, you can work with [threading.Timer](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#threading.Timer), but you need to do a little more work to get it to start at a given time, run every five minutes, and stop at a fixed time.

Comment: Hi Raymond thank you for your answer, unfortunately I have been using python for about 1 week following youtube tutorials, I find the python documentation pages very unhelpful (currently) as it is written for more experienced coders by more experienced coders. I wish they would put a comment on each line of the example to explain what it was doing. :(

Comment: The code I have so far created, works fine scraping a website and parsing the data I want, but i haven't gone into multi threading this code yet. I am not sure its required (time will tell)

Comment: @AEA Doug Hellman's version will give you a much more gentle introduction to the Python standard library modules:  http://pymotw.com/2/sched/index.html#module-sched

Comment: Thanks Raymond! I would give you some reputation but i dont think i can until I have 15 points my self! Many thanks!

Comment: Hello Raymond, i wasn't sure if i should start a new topic or continue this here, im sure a mod will slap my wrist if i'm in the wrong. I managed to get the loop working correctly using the code: `run_periodically(time()+5, time()+1000000, 300, getData)
` I presume i can replace the term `time` with different objects (please note i'm not up to speed with the jargon yet.) So i could make the first `time` something like `StartTime` but I dont know how to define a start time in python, what is the standard format for time? Do we do seconds from the start of the day???

Comment: I did search for this but to no avail :s